# Designing a form in SharePoint 2010 based on list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I want to design a form like on the image below in SharePoint page based on the list data.
Can anyone tell me the way to do this?

[image]

and i tried the same thing using SharePoint designer, i did like this only.

1. I cannot able to rename the button name, alignment like the above page.
2. The table style .

[image]

Comment: do you want it to look exactly like your screenshot? including the list view in the bottom?

Comment: I don't understand the desired functionality from the screen shot -- is the bottom part simply to specify the 'Appointment Type' and add some notes? Can you select multiple appointment types? Should each one have notes of its own? If you click 'edit' on an appointment type at the bottom can you just edit the 'Description' field or are there other things to edit?

Comment: My colleague has done this form using visual studio 2010. that screenshot only i displayed above.But i want to do without any external application. Main task is to design a form like this,if i enter the appointment type in the text box and click the save button means it should be added in the table below the form. is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

When I want to change the style of one of the default forms I use something like this. The key is creating a new html form, and giving each element you want to include a span tag with the name "hillbillyform". Then the script will look for these fields, and apply the styles that you choose. This is applied using a CEWP on the form you desire to modify.

I've had great success with this in SharePoint 2010, but have not had a need to try this in SharePoint 2013. This concept was base on a demo given by Mark Rackely, titled "Easy Custom Layouts"

```
<h1>Beautiful New Form</h1> 
<div style="display:table; table-layout:fixed;" id="hillbillyform"> 
<div style="display:table-row><div style="display:table-cell"><b>Title:</b><br/><span  id="hillybilly1" data-displayName="Title"></span></div> 
<div style="display:table-cell"><b>Description:</b><br/><span id="hillbilly2" data- displayName="Description"></span></div></div> 
</div> 

Modified Script File: 
<style type="text/css"> 
.ms-formtable 
{display:none;} 
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript">   
    var newfields = document.getElementById("hillbillyform").querySelectorAll("[data-   displayName]"); 
var oldfields = document.querySelectorAll("table.ms-formtable td"); 
for(var i=0; i<newfields.length; i++) 
    { 
        displayName = newfields[i].getAttribute("data-displayName"); 
        elem = document.getElementById(newfields[i].id);    
        for(var j=0; j < oldfields.length; j++){ 
            if (oldfields[j].innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){ 
                elem.appendChild(oldfields[j]); 
break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself an ASPX page in SPD and use a page viewer web part above you list for the form.  Then, either use the REST API, CSOM, or SPServices to create the new list item on submit.  I like using SPServices myself, but either JQuery list interaction will give the same result for a new list item.

Edit:

You are over thinking it.  I just did what you wanted in 10 minutes (basically a few tweeks needed, but I am not doing the whole thing for you) just to give you an idea of what to do.

```
<style>

.mainTable {
margin-left:200px;

}

.button1 {
margin-right:50px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="mainTable">
<table cellpadding="5px">
<tr><td><asp:Label runat="server">Appointment Type:</asp:Label></td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:Label runat="server">Description:</asp:Label></td><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="60px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:Label runat="server">Status:</asp:Label></td><td><asp:CheckBox runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="button1"></asp:Button><asp:Button runat="server"     Text="Cancel"></asp:Button></td></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Use your own code make your table Then use Jquery to populate the values of the list.  The dataView will pick up the updates when the page is updated.  You will need to do a lot more that this but just to give you an idea that what you are doing is not too difficult.  Just dont over-think it :)

Comment: i have added separate aspx page and added the form using SharePoint list form control and that will not be in same format as i mention above in the screen shot

Comment: If you make your own ASPX file from a blank page, you can add your own CSS to it to make it look like you want. Then use JQuery to update your list items on button click. What you have is very simple to do as far as looks and CSS needs.  You can get the table view by using a DataView Web Part.

Comment: yes . i got the table view using DataView WebPart. but how to design the table and make the button to alignment . I can't able to customize.. its not working yar

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SPD to create your own New/Edit/Display form based on the list columns. You can basically do any changes in the SPD and you do not have to create your own interface/methods for CRUD operations.

To display data from another list you can add web part to your form in SPD (or in browser add &ToolPaneView=2 to your url) with list view. Or you can use JS to query the list and display it in any form you want. For this I would recommend jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)